# Do we have access to SE user database to track our community growth?

Tags: discussion

My impression is that delta increase of registered users is growing every day e.g we might have entered some accelerated growth phase.

Is there any data available to make a graph, or even an existing dashboard with such a graph?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play with

- [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/devops/queries) to make queries on the site posts.
- have a look at [quancast](https://www.quantcast.com/devops.stackexchange.com)
- checks [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops)
- And lastly hit the [5 000 reputation points](https://devops.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to gain access to the statistics page which present this information.

Btw I can confirm your impression that on the last week the rate of new users is on a raising curve.

Comment: thank you so much for these insights! by the way another one valid option is to wait a couple of weeks or so to learn these 5K points insights from @Tensibai :-)

Comment: @J.Doe I already have access to the same kind of pages as a moderator, but I should not disclose the numbers there :)

Answer (score 5):

Here is a graph of new DevOps users per day. It's very stable, with a natural  weekly cycle. The first peak is the first day of private beta. I don't know the cause of the second peak in early April; could be a Reddit post about something on the site, etc.

[image: new users]

Source: [SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/devops/query/80302/new-users-per-day#graph)

Comment: @Tensibai - so there is no rising curve and our subjective impression was wrong? :/

Comment: ^^ however in this form of graph we see a linear growth with slightly more subsequent "growth" speedup "upstairs segments" than before. Looking forward to further development. :-)

Comment: @J.Doe depends on what you call new users, newly registered users to the site (this query results) or new users of the site as new connexion. You may observe also the results graph stops on Sunday (the data stops on Monday 17) and are per day. I was more talking about a 7 day average of new visits to the site than newly registered users. The graph for new posts show the same curve and is a better representation of the site activity as is the number of visits per day.

Comment: Was coming back to recheck and reread the answer: the second peak match with the public beta opening I think.

Answer (score 0):

I've been regularly checking the [Users page (new users, creation date tabs)](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=newusers&sort=creationdate) - shows all users that signed up in the past 46 days. There are peaks now and then - mostly at the beginning of the work week, but the average remained fairly constant in the past few months.